# Resetting Label and Callout positioning for a single Label in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, callout

I accidentally altered the endpoints for a callout and cannot figure out how to reset them. I tried a number of key combinations while clicking the endpoints but nothing seems to help.

Is there a way to go back to the "default" callout endpoints for individuals labels/callouts?

Comment: Later, whilst trying to do something else in the attribute table I saw the additional fields that adjusting labels/callouts adds, so I deleted the data there and they are reset now. I'll wait to see if other folks have other suggested ways of achieving the same thing before adding this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you did it is (I believe) the only available route to resetting a single labels properties. It would be nice if you could right click on a modified label and have an option "Reset to default", but so far the best way is to:

1. Note the Unique ID number for the feature whose label you want to reset
2. double click on the layer to bring up it's properties
3. Select Auxiliary Storage from the left side panel
4. Highlight and remove the label modifications associated with previously noted unique id